# Windows Help Shows Blank Window

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, help-files

I use Access 2000, and when I am using the VBA IDE, I sometimes press F1 for help on a certain keyword.  Afterwards, the help window shows, but it's a blank white window with a title bar stating "Microsoft Visual Basic Help."  What is strange is that it works depending on the keyword.  It probably works for certain help files and not others that are referenced in the project.

Nevertheless, I have tried the steps here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249065

I have also added a key to the registry:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x\ItssRestrictions
Key: MaxAllowedZone
Value: 1

I have also performed a detect and repair.

This does not seem to work.  I know I was successful in repairing this issue on a previous computer, but I am unable to locate the proper steps to correct it again.  The OS is Windows XP all patched up, and it does have IE8 installed.  I mention that because I seem to remember the issue having something to do with Internet Explorer settings.

How do I get the help file to show content?  I'll continue to struggle to figure it out, but if any of you have any tips or suggestions, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I took a much closer at my installation, and I feel like a dufus.  I had created a custom setup file for my installation of Office 2000, and I apparently did not set it up correctly to install the VBA help files.  When I went to Control Panel > Add or Remove Programs > Microsoft Office 2000 SR-1 Professional > Change > Add or Remove Features, I discovered I needed to include the VBA Help Files among many other things that did not get installed.

After testing it, the help files work fine.

Thank you!